# WebSockets authentication

Tags: security, websocket

What are the possible ways to authenticate user when websocket connection is used?

Example scenario: Web based multi-user chat application through encrypted websocket connection. How can I ensure (or guarantee) that each connection in this application belongs to certain authenticated user and "can't be" exploited by false user impersonation during the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL/TLS can be used to authenticate both client and server using X.509 certificates.   It depends on the web application platform you are using.   In apache the SSL_CLIENT_CERT [environment variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html) can be checked for validity against a list of known certificates to be valid.   This would not require the use of a full PKI,  and would not require you to purchase certificates for each client.  Although I recommend using a CA to back your server's ssl certificate.

Comment: You mean that SSL certificate will be used for HTTP and WebSocket connection respectively?

Comment: I dis-agree what rook said. SSL/TLS can ensure the data is not changed in transport layer. But the problem here is that how can we know the web socket request is from user A not user B? Image both user A and B are logged in. As web-socket does not send cookie after the connection is established. So in later, how does this web-socked ensure the request is from the real user A rather than user B?

Answer (score 44):

If you're already doing authentication for the non-websocket part of your app, just pass the session cookie along as the first message after connecting and check the cookie as you normally would.

**WARNING: It's been pointed out that the following doesn't work when flashsockets are used:**
If you're using [socket.io](http://socket.io), it's even easier—the cookies are passed through automatically on connection, and can be accessed like the following:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.listen(app); 
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
    cookies = client.headers['cookie'];
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that this always works? If Socket.IO falls back onto Flash sockets, for example, browser cookies won't (AFAIK) get sent.

Comment: @Thomas you're right, there's an [issue filed](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/101) that mentions that you should do authentication via the first message instead.

Comment: This is a practical method, but it requires the Web page that does the login (and cookie setting) to come from the same origin as the WebSocket, since otherwise the cookie (set from the login page) won't get sent on the WebSocket connection.

Comment: Depending on cookies is a bad idea, because cross-origin WebSockets are allowed and will pass cookies associated with the destination url.  This leaves you wide open to CORS attacks, unless you're checking the Origin header as well.

Comment: Cookies don't work if you use CORS. SocketCluster used to use cookies to store JWT tokens but has since moved away from it. See https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster-client/issues/9

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

One way is to allow anyone to open a websocket connection. Have the client send an authorization token as the first message after the connection is opened. If the client doesn't send a valid token within some time, close the connection.

Another way is to use cookies (they're sent automatically by the browser on each request). This requires that you implement CSRF protection (even more than normal, since there is no same origin policy (SOP) for websockets. You can find details [here](https://gist.github.com/kag0/f3c43b60b700af39563c050b29a3dfb2). The outline is as follows:

1. make a "websocket preauth" request to the backend from js using the site's normal auth
2. backend returns a CSRF token in the response body and sets a "websocket auth" cookie with `SameSite=Strict` in the response headers
3. attempt to establish a websocket connection with the backend, with the addition of the CSRF token in a query parameter
4. the backend checks

   - that the websocket auth cookie and CSRF token are valid
   - that the value of the `Origin` header matches an approved domain
5. the backend sends a response and upgrades the connection to use websockets

The first method is simpler, but has the disadvantage that it requires you to have some server-side state waiting for the client to authenticate. This can allow an attacker to perform a denial of service attack by consuming all the available sockets.