# Delegated Authentication using websockets

Tags: security, authentication, websocket

I have googled "[websocket delegated authentication](https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket%20delegated%20authentication)" and the only interesting hit is (unsurprisingly) on stackoverflow: [WebSockets authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701373/websockets-authentication)

What I'd like to know is: how are you allowing client-side applications - connected via websockets - to delegate their authority to back-end services and data stores?

I'm especially interested in figuring out how to delegate x509-based authentication, but at this point, I'd be happy to hear anyone's account of how they're delegating authority from the client-side over websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what tech you are using php, net, java? Anyway for plain formsauth we just use the cookie passed from the browser with the websocket connection. We can then tell if the client has access or not. Have also used certificates (x509) wss/tls

If you are a .NET guy here's some docs
http://xsockets.net/api/net-c#
You will find both wss/tls and formsauth at the bottom of the page.

Comment: using Java, but a .NET solution would be okay too.  Neither of those seem to be able to allow the receiving service to continue to pass the client's credentials (delegation).