# Websocket application and authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication, websocket

*Hello and thanks for reading!*

So I am using node.js with websockets (ws) for a web application, and I would like to know what the best options are for authenticating clients. Please forgive my ignorance!

**What I want to achieve:**

A multiplayer app that can authenticate users using login/pwd and then keep some sort of "session" active

**What I know from my PHP experience:**

Client typing login+pwd > server searches DB > server tells client he logged in and opens a "session" (which then can be used to do stuff without having to reauthenticate at every request)

**I have found the following clues:**

[WebSockets authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701373/websockets-authentication)
...but my knowledge of network programming is very limited. How can I use SSL to authenticate my clients? I read something about using cookies too?

**So...**

- SSL? Cookies? How to use it concretely?
- Some way to use the PHP session?
- Do it all in the server code? (Access DB and authenticate with javascript in server code);
- ...?

I would really appreciate it if you could help me on this topic, I wouldn't post if I didn't feel so clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/) as module for websockets. You will find many examples here on stackoverflow on how to connect sessions to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using einaros/ws as module, should I consider using socket.io instead until more tutorials are available for ws? I have read on a few occasions that ws was the new thing.

Comment: You should. Socket.io version > 1.0 definitely already is the thing. Well documented, many usage examples and support for sessions built in. The syntax is similar to ws, shouldn't be a lot of trouble to switch.