# How can I authenticate websocket connection

Tags: authentication, websocket, backend

What is a common approach in authenticating of user session for websocket connection?

As I understand websocket message contains data only with no headers. Thus authorization cookie is not available to server backend. How should application distinguish messages from different clients?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSockets authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701373/websockets-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which websocket server are you using?

if your webserver and websocketserver are the same, you could send the sessionid via websocket and force-disconnect any client that does not send a valid sessionid in his first message.

if your websocketserver parses the HTTP headers sent in the HTTP upgrade request properly, it may also save any cookie. this is what a request of my firefox (version 35) looks like:

```
GET /whiteboard HTTP/1.1
Host: *:*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: *
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: whiteboard
Sec-WebSocket-Key: iGPS0jjbNiGAYrIyC/YCzw==
Cookie: PHPSESSID=9fli75enklqmv1a30hbdmg1461
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

as you see, the phpsessionid is transmitted fine. check the documentation of your websocketserver if it parses the HTTP headers. remember that cookies will not be sent if the websocket's domain differs from the webserver's domain.

Comment: I got a websocketserver as a separate process. Should I provide web page with auth token, which then I should use in a script that establishes websocket connection and pass the tocken to hte websocket server in the first message from the page?

Comment: that's one way to do it.

depending on your websocketserver, you may also use the cookies sent in the HTTP upgrade request. i will edit my answer.

Comment: Does that mean that WS library should provide onConnect event with handshaking headers?

Comment: well, if your websocketserver and webserver are running on the same domain _and_ your websocketserver parses the cookie, you dont need the workaround.
if not, send the sessionid as soon as the connection is established:
`ws.onopen  = function(){ws.send("COOKIE "+document.cookie);}`

Comment: That's good news.  I didn't think cookies were working with my websockets, but they are: it must have been my code that was wrong.