# How to authenticate WebSocket connection

Tags: authentication, websocket

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security
Why is the ticket-based authentication system as described in this article more necessary than something like sending a username and password in the first websocket message and authenticating the connection like that?

Comment: I don't get it either. The standard `Authorization:` header works fine when connecting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSockets authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701373/websockets-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

> sending a username and password in the first websocket message

That would require that you either re-prompt the user for their password (annoying) or store the user password in browser storage (very bad) until the websocket session is started.